# scaling my web application using n app servers and dao as webserice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, scaling

Suppose i have number of app servers as APP1,APP2,APP3 ...  APPN.

Now all app servers should access the same DB.

So i though of putting DAO along with DB on seperate machine machine and exposing DAO as
webservice

Will it help me in scaling my web based application?

I plan  to use following architecture

```
           load banncer
 appS1  appS2   .....        appSn   

       dao as webservice
       DB
```

Is it a good idea?
How can i handle session mangagement in such architecture?

Comment: not bad, you can also cache some of the results in the web service within the memory. you can also put cache in from of web services. and you can have a memory cache within your apps. that would scale better.

Comment: Is it the best approach? and by cashing u mean cashing at DAO level right(level3 in above dia)?or at appserver level?I am planning to use hibernate cashing at dao level

Comment: it s not cashing. should be caching. not sure about hibernate caching but you can use for instance memcached between app servers and dao. and within appservers and web services use in memory caching, to store most frequently used data or query results. you can also store data as collections and query colllections.

Comment: How do you plan to implement transactional services with such an architecture? Why would it scale better than simply have each app server access the DB directly? Now not only do you have the DB as a single access point, but also the DAO. Unless the services do very complex and time-consuming in-memory computations, my guess is that this will be worse than having a single server accessing the DB directly.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I am planning to use some cashing at DAO layer, hibernate cashing for example.So we are not hitting db each time but we can server from DAO cash sometimes

Comment: Then use a Hibernate second-level cache on each app server. If the cached data is read-only, you don't need anything more. If it isn't, you might need a clustered second-level cache. But the DAO layer must be in every app server.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is OK. But DAO as web-service may not cope up with increasing load, plus webservice requests may add network overhead. What I would suggest is to keep your app as it, add some caching (may require some code change) and scale out your app-servers, and Database.

To scale horizontally the general approach is to add more app-servers and more slaves to your DBMS. This usually accompanied by adding caching servers like MemcacheD that are used to cache your value-objects and generally, frequently required objects that do not modify much over time. Caching responds faster than query, as the results are cached.

The above approach we have been using for some eight years. With recent changes in the way data is stored, and infrastructure availability; a mode daring(*it may be real pain in neck to modify an existing app*) step is to modify your app (partially or completely) to use a no-sql data-store, these datastores are specifically made for heavy read-write. There are many options if you go this way -- Cassandra, MongoDB, Dynamo, and [many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

- [Scaling MySQL](http://natishalom.typepad.com/nati_shaloms_blog/2008/03/scaling-out-mys.html)
- [Cassandra to scale web-app](http://www.divconq.com/2010/why-cassandra/)